# az acr login with subject name and issuer authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to authenticate to Azure container registry with the cli.
I'm using subject name and issuer authentication, and authenticating to azure with service principal.

that's what I do to login to azure

```
az login --service-principal --use-cert-sn-issuer -u {app id} -p {certificate .pem file} --tenant {tenant id}
```

it works, and then I try to login to the acr with:

```
 az acr login --name {acr name}
```

it fails with:

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: {Thumbprint}, Please visit 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' and query for 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{app id}' to see configured keys]\r\nTrace ID: 4546d682-75b6-4a8b-9c03-11f4821c5f00\r\nCorrelation ID: 02e4c324-25a9-47ff-a5ba-afdeec0ce5ec\r\nTimestamp: 2020-06-23 08:12:00Z","error_codes":[700027],"timestamp":"2020-06-23 08:12:00Z","trace_id":"4546d682-75b6-4a8b-9c03-11f4821c5f00","correlation_id":"02e4c324-25a9-47ff-a5ba-afdeec0ce5ec","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700027"}
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your certificate is not very correct. Here is the same [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/issues/453) in Github and you can follow the steps to solve it.

Or you can create the service principal using certificate-based authentication with the CLI command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName --create-cert
```

and then it will work fine for you. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) are the steps with more details. And take care of the caution:

> When using a PEM file, the CERTIFICATE must be appended to the PRIVATE
> KEY within the file.

Comment: I opened an issue for it, and they are fixing it https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14072

Comment: @DanaShviro The answer is also a way to fix it. Do you try it?

Comment: I'm not using a certificate that is connected directly to my service principle I use "Subject name and issuer authentication", in the past I used a certificate that is connected to the service principle, and it worked. its a bug on the azure cli that will be solved on their next release